# Example of ring such that the nil radical is prime and 0 is not

Tags: commutative-algebra

I was just trying to think about an example of a ring that is not a domain and the nilradical is prime, however I could not find anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ works.

Comment: Any prime power works.

Comment: It was easier than I thought. I tried to pick rings with only one prime ideal.